# Temporary access to page with URL sent to email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password

I want to protect a certain page with a password. The thing is that I want to get it unlocked to users who have an active booking (I'm using WooCommerce Bookings). I have thought that a good idea could be to send an email to every user with an active booking X minutes before the actual booking starts with a private and temporary link to that locked page. The link should use a token to have it unlocked automatically.
I don't know if this is possible in the WordPress environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The users could be sent a link with parameters: "{url}/booking0914?token=zxy321"  Your action hook would allow users with the correct token to proceed.  Others would be redirected.